# Maven duplicated files in ZIP

Tags: java, maven

I'm using mvn 3.3.1 in a Windows 8.1 machine with Java 8.

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-13T21:10:27+01:00)
Maven home: C:\bin\apache-maven-3.3.1
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Default locale: es_ES, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

The problem is that when I generate a new deployment package for my app with `mvn clean install` the ZIP file that is generated has, inside it, on some folders, two files with the same filename.

[Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sJsl.jpg)

I know that one file cames from the "product" version of our software, and the other one is the customization, for a specific client, for which we are building the delivery. The thing is that the client customization should have OVERWRITTEN the other file, and that's not what is happening, it is, somehow, adding both files which, when you try to uncompress the generated ZIP file, gives up an error.

This error is only happening with Windows.
The same repository, with same assembly files, is working fine on Linux machines with maven, OSX machines, and a Linux server with jenkins building versions after each git commit.

Anyone knows how can I force maven on windows to overwrite files ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, don't put the same file into the archive. The ZIP format allows files with the same name in a folder. Something is off with your Maven build path, you should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to *exclude* explicitly some files from the zip construction:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>...</exclude>
                    <exclude>...</exclude>
                    <exclude>...</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Take a look at the [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) documentation.